# Sign in users with Google Auth Library for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, google-api, google-signin

I want to sign in users with the [google-auth-library-ruby](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-ruby)
 gem.

In their guides "Google Sign-In for server-side apps " they have [a good code example](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#step_7_exchange_the_authorization_code_for_an_access_token) how to exchange the authorization code for an ID token, but it's only for Python (and Java):

```
credentials = client.credentials_from_clientsecrets_and_code(
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE,
['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.appdata', 'profile', 'email'],
auth_code)
```

Does anybody know about the equivalent for Ruby?

PS. I'm familiar with the omniauth gem, but would like to use the `google-auth-library-ruby` gem if possible.

Comment: I'm also looking for this, did you find it?

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't... :/

Comment: July 2019 and still nothing...

Answer (score 2):

After some research, I found [this collection of samples](https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-ruby/blob/master/examples/authentication/authenticate_in_standalone_application.rb), where the `googleauth` gem is used. Here you have it:

```ruby
client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.new("your Google client ID", "your Google secret")
scope = ["email","profile"] 
token_store = nil # there are actually already implemented File or Redis token stores
callback_url = "http://localhost:8000"

authorizer = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new(client_id, scope, token_store, callback_url)

credentials = authorizer.get_credentials_from_code(code: "the auth code in the Sign In response")
```